# C++ ошибка сегментации

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, права-доступа

Уже несколько дней пытаюсь найти ошибку, все никак не получается :(. При этом смотрю на пример, который мы делали с другом, делаю в этой работе все также, но что-то не так.

Привожу фрагмент кода:

```
class stack{ // класс "стек"
public:
    class cars{ //класс машины (марки машин)
    public:
        string mark;
        string color;
        string adress;
        int price;

        cars(){} // конструктор умолчания

        cars(string m, string c, int p, string a){ // конструктор инициализации
            mark = m;
            color = c;
            adress = a;
            price = p;
        }

       cars operator=(cars cc){ // оператор присваивания машин
           mark = cc.mark;
           color = cc.color;
           adress = cc.adress;
           price = cc.price;
           return *this;
       }

        void print(){ // вывод элементов на уровне класса "машины"
            cout << endl << mark << ", цвет: " << color << ", цена: " << price << " адрес: " << adress << endl;

        }
        ~cars(){} // деструктор
    };

    stack (){ // конструктор умолчания
        car = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }


    int size = 0; // количество машин в стекек (сначала 0)
    cars *car; // машины в стеке


    void push(){ // добавление элементов

        int price;
        string mark, color, adress, pric;


        cout << "\nВведите марку машины: ";

        cin >> mark;

        cout << "\nВведите цвет машины: ";

        cin >> color;

        cout << "\nВведите цену: ";

        cin >> pric;

        price = iscorrect(pric);

        cout << "\nВведите адрес: ";

        cin.ignore();

        getline(cin, adress);

        cars ccc(mark, color, price, adress);

        ccc.print();


        size++;
        if (size == 1)  car = (cars*)malloc(1 * sizeof(cars)); // если в стэке пока нет машин, назначить память для первой  
        else  car = (cars*)realloc(car, size * sizeof(cars)); //иначе назначит на текущее количество + следующий элемент
        car[size - 1]=ccc; 
        cout << "\nЭта машина успешно добавлена в список\n";            
    }

    void pop() { // удаление элементов
        car[size - 1].print();
        size--;
        car = (cars*)realloc(car, (size) * sizeof(cars)); //переназначение памяти
        cout << "\nЭта машина успешно удалена.\n";
    }
class stack{ // класс "стек"
public:
    class cars{ //класс машины (марки машин)
    public:
        string mark;
        string color;
        string adress;
        int price;

        cars(){} // конструктор умолчания

        cars(string m, string c, int p, string a){ // конструктор инициализации
            mark = m;
            color = c;
            adress = a;
            price = p;
        }

       cars operator=(cars cc){ // оператор присваивания машин
           mark = cc.mark;
           color = cc.color;
           adress = cc.adress;
           price = cc.price;
           return *this;
       }

        void print(){ // вывод элементов на уровне класса "машины"
            cout << endl << mark << ", цвет: " << color << ", цена: " << price << " адрес: " << adress << endl;

        }
        ~cars(){} // деструктор
    };

    stack (){ // конструктор умолчания
        car = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }


    int size = 0; // количество машин в стекек (сначала 0)
    cars *car; // машины в стеке


    void push(){ // добавление элементов

        int price;
        string mark, color, adress, pric;


        cout << "\nВведите марку машины: ";

        cin >> mark;

        cout << "\nВведите цвет машины: ";

        cin >> color;

        cout << "\nВведите цену: ";

        cin >> pric;

        price = iscorrect(pric);

        cout << "\nВведите адрес: ";

        cin.ignore();

        getline(cin, adress);

        cars ccc(mark, color, price, adress);

        ccc.print();


        size++;
        if (size == 1)  car = (cars*)malloc(1 * sizeof(cars)); // если в стэке пока нет машин, назначить память для первой  
        else  car = (cars*)realloc(car, size * sizeof(cars)); //иначе назначит на текущее количество + следующий элемент
        car[size - 1]=ccc; 
        cout << "\nЭта машина успешно добавлена в список\n";            
    }

    void pop() { // удаление элементов
        car[size - 1].print();
        size--;
        car = (cars*)realloc(car, (size) * sizeof(cars)); //переназначение памяти
        cout << "\nЭта машина успешно удалена.\n";
    }
```

clang version 7.0.0-3~ubuntu0.18.04.1 (tags/RELEASE_700/final)
Весь можно запустить здесь: https://repl.it/repls/DarksalmonCrookedPaint#main.cpp

В чем сама проблема: почему-то только если добавить один элемент, потом сразу удалить его, после попытки добавления еще одного элемента выходит ошибка сегментации.
Но дело в том, что если изначально добавить два элемента и больше, никакая ошибка не появляется: хоть добавь два, потом удали их, опять же как выше добавь один и сразу удали его. Все будет хорошо. Привожу скриншоты:
Вот первый случай:
[image: Это первый случай]

А вот второй:
[image: А это второй]

В среде Visual Studio 19 ошибка такая:
[image: Ошибка в студии]

Кажется, моих неглубоких знаний не хватит, чтобы понять суть этой проблемы, поэтому я очень рассчитываю на помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: слушайте, вы понимаете что такое стэк? Как устроен стэк? То что вы написали - это не стэк, даже не близко. В стэке ноды идут одна за одной, при этом каждая последующая нода ссылается на родителя. А у вас внутри просто массив, который релацируется и вы наивно полагаете, что это должно работать...

Comment: Не надо в принципе смешивать французский с нижегородским! `realloc` и С++ (не POD-типы), мягко говоря, очень взрывоопасная смесь. Тем более что вы нигде не проверяете его результат.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch В данном случае не соглашусь - почему вы решили, что стек - это только списочная структура? Стек вообще-то определяется исключительно интерфейсом - push/pop, а уж как его реализовывать - дело другое.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch работа сделана по примеру преподавателя. Возможно, вы и правы, но я хочу узнать только причину ошибки

Comment: @Harry Подскажите, пожалуйста, как тогда нужно делать. Наш преподаватель учил использовать realloc для динамического переназначения памяти. Также в примере моего друга, который мы делали вместе, тоже используются такие же алгоритмы добавления и удаления (могу показать, если хотите). Но у него нет такой ошибки.

Comment: @Harry пожалуй вы правы по поводу внутренней реализации - все таки да, стэк - это не обязательно списочная структура (хотя для большинства случаев и особенно для этого, ИМХО, это более подхадящая реализация, чем на массиве)

Comment: Забыл важную пометку. В студии выходит ошибка уже при первой же попытке добавить элемент.

Comment: В операторе присваивания просходит зацикливание : `cars operator=(cars cc); ` Вы принимаете и возвращаете новый объект по значению. А надо по ссылке: `cars & operator=(cars const & cc); `.

Comment: @Kreetyk вас это преподаватель надоумил использовать `realloc` для классов? Скомпилируйте вашу программу со включенными варнингами - компилятор вам сам объяснит почему в c++ нужно использовать `new` и `delete`

Comment: Маллок и реаллок возвращают неинициализированную память, а не массив объектов.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch преподаватель учил так переопределять размер массива еще в С. В работе и есть массив внутри класса, я не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. New и Delete понятно, а как переопределить размер тогда?

Comment: @AlexGlebe не помогло :(

Comment: C **malloc** и **realloc** будете очень долго писать. Пользуйтесь, например `std::deque<cars>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы объяснить ситуацию (на которую вам вообще-то указывает компилятор, о чем я писал в комментах) приведу небольшой пример:

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Tmp {
public:
  Tmp() {
    str = "string";
    std::cout << "constructor" << std::endl;
  }
  Tmp &operator=(const Tmp &rhs) {
    str = rhs.str;
    std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }
  ~Tmp() {
    std::cout << "destructor" << std::endl;
  }

  std::string str;
};

int main() {
  Tmp *val = (Tmp *)malloc(1 * sizeof(Tmp));

  Tmp stackVal;

  *val = stackVal;

  free(val);
}
```

Как видим у нас есть базовый класс который содержит в себе строку а конструктор по умолчанию, копирующий конструктор и деструктор я реализовал с выводом, чтобы было видно когда они вызываются. Запустим:

```sh
constructor
copy constructor
destructor
```

Казалось бы ничего не обычного, но если присмотреться: у нас было вызвано два консруктора - и всего один деструктор... Для наглядности как это работает с `new` и `delete`:

```cpp
int main() {
  Tmp *val = new Tmp;

  Tmp stackVal;

  *val = stackVal;

  delete (val);
}
```

Вывод:

```sh
constructor
constructor
copy constructor
destructor
destructor
```

Вот это уже другой дело. Но почему так? Да потому что `malloc`, `free` и `realloc` сишный функции, они ничего не знают о конструкторах и деструкторах! Если бы вы скомпилировали ваш код с включенными варнингами то обнаружили бы что-то типа того:

```sh
main.cpp:27:49: warning: ‘void* realloc(void*, size_t)’ moving an object of non-trivially copyable type ‘class Tmp’; use ‘new’ and ‘delete’ instead [-Wclass-memaccess]
```

Но почему же тогда код с `malloc` и т.п. работает у вашего друга? - спросите вы. А не работает он и там, только там еще хуже, потому что программа не падает сразу. Посмотрим на следующий пример:

```cpp
int main() {
  Tmp *val = (Tmp *)malloc(1 * sizeof(Tmp));

  std::memset((char *)val, 1, sizeof(Tmp));

  Tmp stackVal;

  *val = stackVal;

  free(val);
}
```

И мы получаем `segmentation fault`. Но вы же сами установили невалидные значения в память выделенную под `val` - конечно оно падает! - скажете вы. На что я отвече: да, я установил невалидные значения в память, выделенную под эту переменную, НО, а откуда там могут взятся валидные значения? `malloc` - повторюсь, ничего не знает о конструкторах! И доже память, которую он выделяет, не обязательно забита нулями - там находится мусор! Просто иногда так получается, что там находятся одни нули и все "как бы работает" - но нет, оно не работает!

В заключение: используйте `new` и `delete`

Comment: Так, вроде немного разобрался. Спасибо Вам! Так бы реально и не понял, в чем ошибка. Получается, если у меня есть массив рассчитанный на 25 элементов, надо добавить 26-ой, придется создавать еще один на 26, копировать в него первые 25, добавить новый элемент и удалить старый массив?

Comment: @Kreetyk во-первых релокация массива - затратная операция, если уж она и нужна, то лучше это делать как можно реже (смотрите ответ Harry), во-вторых, как я указывал в комментариях, в вашем случае лучше подойдет стэк основанный на односвязном списке

Answer (score 1):

Раз вы хотите кода... Я бы делал примерно [так](https://ideone.com/2KdrVy):

```
class Car{ //класс машины (марки машин)
public:
    Car(){} // конструктор умолчания
    Car(string m, string c, int p, string a):mark(m),color(c),adress(a),price(p){}
    Car(const Car&)            = default;
    Car& operator=(const Car&) = default;
    ~Car()                     = default;

    void print(){ // вывод элементов на уровне класса "машины"
        cout << endl << mark << ", цвет: " << color << ", цена: " << price << " адрес: " << adress << endl;
    }
private:
    string mark;
    string color;
    string adress;
    int price;
};

Car read()
{
    int price;
    string mark, color, adress;
    cout << "\nВведите марку машины: ";
    cin >> mark;
    cout << "\nВведите цвет машины: ";
    cin >> color;
    cout << "\nВведите адрес: ";
    cin >> adress;
    cout << "\nВведите цену: ";
    cin >> price;
    return Car(mark, color, price, adress);
}

class stack { // класс "стек"
public:
    stack(): cars(new Car[4]), size(0), capacity(4) {}
    stack(const stack&) = delete;
    stack& operator=(const stack&) = delete;
    ~stack() { delete[] cars; }

    void push(const Car& c)
    {
        if (size == capacity)
        {
            Car * tmp = new Car[capacity*=2];
            for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) tmp[i] = cars[i];
            delete[] cars;
            cars = tmp;
        }
        cars[size++] = c;
    }
    Car pop()
    {
        if (size == 0) throw runtime_error("Stack is empty");
        return cars[--size];
    }
private:
    int size, capacity;
    Car *cars;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    stack st;
    st.push(read());
    st.pop().print();
    st.push(read());
    st.push(read());
    st.pop().print();
    st.pop().print();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за потраченное время, но я хочу понять суть ошибки в своем коде, чтобы избежать их в будущем :(. В Вашем есть некоторые непонятные мне вещи.